# CSS проблемы с ::before

Tags: css, псевдоэлемент

на оригинальном сайте, при наведении на ссылку в меню, появляется зеленая полоса, индивидуальная для каждого элемента списка. Я скопировал оттуда стили, но у меня полоса сплошная на весь родительский блок, почему так?

[image: Оригинал]
[image: Мое]

```
        .catalog__wrapper {
}
.catalog__wrapper ul {
    width: 100%;
    text-align-last: justify;
    margin: 1rem auto 2rem;
}
.catalog__wrapper li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.catalog__wrapper li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.catalog__wrapper li a:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.01px black;
}
.catalog__wrapper li a:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
}
.catalog__wrapper li a::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #5dae38;
    top: calc(100% + 7px);
    width: calc(100% + 24px);
    left: -12px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для `.catalog__wrapper li a` вам нужно задать `position: relative`.

Comment: Действительно, спасибо.